# Greyed out and non interactive preview of plotly in r-markdown in RStudio

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, r-plotly

Yesterday I updated RStudio and R, and since then most of my markdowns cannot show interactive plots of plotly anymore. Instead I get a greyed out plot (which shows the correct plot, but it is grey and non interactive)

The same markdown works still perfectly on my other PC with the old R and RStudio.

I figured out that any kind of console output (see "Not Working I") supresses the interaction.
Also if I plot multiple plots in the same chunk, it also becomes grey and non-interactive (see "Not Working II").
If I just have one plot and I set it up so that no console message is shown, I still get an interactive plot.

Any idea what the issue could be?

**EDIT**: Also if I knit I get "perfect" plots (interactive and not grey)

Here is a minimum working example which shows the problem:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(plotly)
```  

```{r Not Working I}  
plot_ly(economics, x = ~date, y = ~unemploy / pop)
```

```{r Working I}
plot_ly(economics, x = ~date, y = ~unemploy / pop, 
             type = "scatter", mode="markers")
```

```{r Not Working II}
plot_ly(economics, x = ~date, y = ~unemploy / pop, 
             type = "scatter", mode="markers")

plot_ly(economics, x = ~date, y = ~unemploy / pop, 
             type = "scatter", mode="markers")
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It reportedly was a bug which was already fixed with the current daily: https://dailies.rstudio.com/

The fix will also be backported into the current release.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting
`knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning = FALSE)`.
I was having the same issue before and this solved it.
But its probably not the best solution considering that you are disabling  warnings. Currently trying to find an alternative to this quick fix. Perhaps you already found a solution.

Comment: It actually was a bug with RStudio - I reported it and they solved it via the dailies - https://dailies.rstudio.com/

The daily will be retrospectively included in the current release - not sure if that happened yet.